# Exporting a file name from a document library to a standalone Sharepoint sheet

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a request.
I need to create a PowerAutomate, that will read the file names in the document library and save them in a separate sheet (Both Sharepoint Online).

Thank you in advance, I am already clueless, the standard search does not work.

I tried to create a column in the sheet that will read the attachment names but unfortunately to no avail.

I'm expecting: When a new record with an attachment is added to the document library. This will trigger an automation that reads the file name and saves that name as plain text in a separate sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Send an HTTP request action for this and use the REST API to retrieve the items. You can apply a select to retrieve the FileLeafRef (file name).
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :)

I just need the type of document not to be written.